# What's the earliest example in Science Fiction of a robot 100% mimicking a human?

Tags: history-of, robots, science-fiction-genre

The classic example is, of course, Stephen Byerley from Asimov's "[Evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_%28short_story%29)".

Were there SciFi works featuring robots that are able to be indistinguishable from humans (by sight or behavior) prior to that?  (September 1946).

What's the earliest such example?

Comment: Not a winner but honourable mention should go to [The Future Eve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Future_Eve) (1886). *"Hadaly"* is a robotic copy of a woman called, *"Alicia", indistinguishable from the original. What makes this work notable is that it made the word "Android" popular.

Comment: Ah, but was Stephen Byerley a robot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

“Able to be indistinguishable” is highly debatable here<sup>*</sup>, it's not actually science fiction<sup>†</sup> and the word “robot” does not turn up in this text<sup>‡</sup>. But if we allow this work at all, then it may well be the earliest appearance: Oʟɪᴍᴘɪᴀ from E.T.A. Hoffmann's 1816 short story [*Der Sandmann*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Sandmann).

---

*<sub>The protagonist is in fact unable to distinguish her from a human, but it's pretty clear that his senses aren't quite alright. At least the adaption Oʟʏᴍᴘɪᴀ in Jacques Offenbach's [*Les contes d'Hoffmann*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Hoffmann#Act_1_.28Olympia.29) is more of a creepy if beautiful puppet (including a crank mechanism that needs to be regularly used to re-power her mechanical clockwork), that only a drugged madman could possibly mistake for a human.</sub>

<sup>†</sup><sub>I would perhaps call it steampunk fantasy today.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>She's called an *Automat*.</sub>

Comment: This should most definitely count. Olimpia is a construct that behaves and looks like a human and is only later found out not to be one.

Comment: Ha! "A drugged madman"

Answer (score 11):

The [original robots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.U.R.#Robots) in *R.U.R.* by [Karel Čapek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karel_%C4%8Capek) (published in 1920) were very human-like in appearance (they were made of protoplasm, not of metal). Their likeness to humans isn't a central plot point like in “Evidence”, but it is mentioned (“Sulla isn't a person, Miss Glory, she's a robot.”).

Comment: RUR was 1921, right?

Answer (score 9):

One of the earliest Sci-Fi movies with that theme is Fritz Lang's *Metropolis*, wherein one of the main characters is duplicated in appearance using a robot. Dates to 1927. In this one, the robot is in fact made to look exactly like the human character.

[Wikipedia: Metropolis (film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_%28film%29)

Answer (score 4):

Lester Del Rey's **"Helen O'Loy"** (1938) beats out **Evidence** by a few years.